# Adding Lottie animation to Android recyclerview leads to unstable results including views displaying in the wrong place and scrollToPosition bugging

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im creating a simple chat style recyclerview like messenger only super simplified.
It all works perfectly, however when I add a lottie animation to show the other person is typing it causes a lot of instability in the recyclerview.

I used a scrollToPosition function when a new message is inserted so it will auto scroll down to the bottom and make the message visible. This bugs out when i add the lottie file, it wont scroll to the bottom properly maybe only half way down instead.

In addition I noticed when I move down the list the message from index 0 of the list will appear as the most recent index so its now duplicated. All these anomolies fix themselves when I remove the lottie animation from the xml. But I would like to have the ability to show a typing animation like every other chat application on the planet. If someone could help me understand what is going wrong I would be greatly appreciative.

[Video snippet of scrollToPosition failing with lottie animation](https://youtu.be/3i8bV6vq_Wc)

To clarify when I remove the lottie animation from the xml the scrollToPosition works as intended and their is no unusual behaviour.

ViewHolder XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="User Icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/messageCv"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/messageCv"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/feelingfit_app_icon_legacy_circular_v1" />

    <!--<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/typingAnimation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_repeatCount="3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/typing"
        app:lottie_cacheStrategy="strong"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon"
        />-->

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/messageCv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_blue_50"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_gchat_container_other"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/_230sdp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="Message"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:text="Today at 110:00pm"
        android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/messageCv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageCv" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ADAPTER

```
class ReplaceAndEmbraceAdapter
constructor(
    private val dateUtil: DateUtil,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var messageList: MutableList<ReplaceAppModel> = mutableListOf()
    private val appMessage: Int = 1
    private val userMessage: Int = 2
    
    inner class ChatDiffCallback(
        private val oldList: List<ReplaceAppModel>,
        private val newList: List<ReplaceAppModel>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
        }
        override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldList.size
        override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newList.size
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
        }
    }

    fun addChat(list: List<ReplaceAppModel>) = apply {
        val diffCallback = ChatDiffCallback(messageList, list)
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        messageList.clear()
        messageList.addAll(list)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    /* fun addChat(list: List<ReplaceAppModel>) {
         messageList = list
         notifyItemInserted(messageList.size)
     }*/

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            appMessage -> {
                MessageAppViewHolder(
                    RecyclerViewReplaceAndEmbraceAppBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false
                    ),
                    dateUtil
                )
            }

            else -> MessageUserViewHolder(
                RecyclerViewReplaceAndEmbraceUserBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is MessageAppViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(messageList?.get(position))
            }
            is MessageUserViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(messageList?.get(position))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (!messageList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            messageList!!.size
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = messageList[position].id

    class MessageAppViewHolder
    constructor(
        private val binding: RecyclerViewReplaceAndEmbraceAppBinding,
        private val dateUtil: DateUtil
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: ReplaceAppModel?) = with(itemView) {
            binding?.apply {


                 typingAnimation.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                     override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
                     }

                     override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                         typingAnimation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                         message.text =
                             HtmlCompat.fromHtml(item?.message!!, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
                         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.feelingfit_app_icon_legacy_circular_v1)
                         timestamp.text = dateUtil.getCurrentTimestampEDDMMMYYYYHHMM()
                         timestamp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                         messageCv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                         messageCv.fadeIn()
                         timestamp.fadeIn()
                     }

                     override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                     }

                     override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                     }

                 })

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If possible post a gif or video so people can understand and provide solution to your problem

Comment: @VenkateshTalacheeru I added a video snippet to the question

Comment: Place your recycler view above the edit text box..!!

Comment: You can see from the XML it is constrainted above the Edittext. The solution to this is unfortunately no where near this simple and beginner

Comment: Replace the LottieAnimationView with simple ImageView and check whether issue persists? In my opinion, the problem is with constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the available code in my opinion, the problem is with constraints so first try to change constraints of `typingAnimation` and icon w.r.t parent instead of `messageCv`.

But after looking the video, I think you don’t have to put animation in recyclerView/adapter. Just put it below the recyclerView. I mean in between recyclerView and EditText and change visibility when you want to show/hide animation.

If you still want to show animation in recycler view then you should create a separate view for animation view. Which means you will have three viewTypes and viewHolders. This is a better way to do this If you are showing it in recyclerView.

Comment: If I added it to a recyclerview how would I controll it? The recyclerview is populated by an arraylist so I would add a "typingview" to the arraylist, but do I then have to delete it from the list to make it go away?

Comment: If you want to control it through recyclerView then you have to add/remove model in arraylist to show/hide. But why you are so keen to use it in recyclerView when you can handle it outside recyclerView.

Comment: I tried adding it outside the recyclerview at the bottom of the view just above the text input box. But when I make the typing view to visibility.GONE to hide it, the recyclerview resizes to fill the space and theres a slight glitchy flicker on screen for one second

Comment: You can handle that slight glitchy flicker by animating through motion layout. At least your problem of lottie has been solved.